# vue 3 class-based-component to Nuxt 3 Migration

Tags: migration, vuejs3, node-modules, vite, nuxtjs3

Right now we are trying to migrate a Vue 3 Project to Nuxt 3. The biggest problem seems to be with Vite not playing well with vue-property-decorator and vue-class-component.

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-class-component.js?v=3aa03c90 optimized info should be defined                                                                                     09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-class-component.js?v=3aa03c90 optimized info should be defined                                                                                     09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-class-component.js?v=3aa03c90 optimized info should be defined                                                                                     09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-class-component.js?v=3aa03c90 optimized info should be defined (repeated 15 times)                                                                 09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-property-decorator.js?v=fa0bd1c9 optimized info should be defined                                                                                  09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-property-decorator_lib_decorators_Prop.js?v=b3537fa3 optimized info should be defined                                                              09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-property-decorator_lib_decorators_Prop.js?v=b3537fa3 optimized info should be defined                                                              09:52:30  

ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-property-decorator_lib_decorators_Prop.js?v=b3537fa3 optimized info should be defined                                                              09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-property-decorator.js?v=fa0bd1c9 optimized info should be defined                                                                                  09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-property-decorator_lib_decorators_VModel.js?v=fc5ecfd2 optimized info should be defined                                                            09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-property-decorator_lib_decorators_VModel.js?v=fc5ecfd2 optimized info should be defined                                                            09:52:30  


ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/leaflet.js?v=10c8e59f optimized info should be defined
```

and also it cannot find something in downloaded modules:

```
 ERROR  09:52:30 [vite] error while updating dependencies:                                                                                                                                                09:52:30  
Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
node_modules/vue-property-decorator/lib/index.js:3:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
node_modules/vue-property-decorator/lib/index.js:4:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue-class-component/dist/vue-class-component.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
    at failureErrorWithLog (*path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1624:15)
    at *path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1266:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (*path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1046:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (*path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1264:7)
    at *path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1377:14
    at *path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:678:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (*path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:775:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (*path-to-project*\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:644:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
```

Here is `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: `@import "./assets/scss/globals.scss";`
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and Here is an example of how we've been writing components:

```html
<template>
    <header>
        <MenuButton v-model:isOn="menuOpen"></MenuButton>
        <HeaderNav v-model:isOpen="menuOpen"></HeaderNav>
    </header>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import MenuButton from "./MenuButton.vue";
import HeaderNav from "./HeaderNav.vue";

@Options({
    components: { MenuButton, HeaderNav }
})
export default class Header extends Vue {
    menuOpen = false;
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
header {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
```

And here is the File structure

[image: And here is the File structure]

Comment: A month later, what are the results of your attempt?

Comment: It appeared that class-based-components work out of the box the way they would normally in vue 3. No extra packages needed. Property Decorators though are rip, because the original library was written for vue 2. I did get them to work, by basically forking the project and updating all the imports and modifying the slightly. But in general we decided to go with client side vue 3, because Nuxt3 is good and all, but each dependency requires days to get working or will not work at all (at the time of writing, surely it will be fixed after the full release).

Comment: Oh God. 

Can u show example? Or can u answer this question, when u're done?

Comment: Hello! How are you doing with the setting? Can I see your component example?
What are you importing and from where?

Comment: Well, we kinda dropped the NUXT Based project (went with vue3) But the Setup would be the same as for the vue-3 class-based Project, you don't need any extra dependencies or anything like that. Except for the Property decorators. Here is Library that I modified: http://filedropper.com/TY8Soneg BUT I must warn you that it was all VERY experimental, I checked for all of them to work. This library generally has several problems with vue 3, which I didn't manage to fix (like some weird behaviors, like default values not always being set etc.).

Comment: Have you tried vue-facing-decorator? That’s the recommended successor to vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator now